# Pandas - re-arrange columns by ascending order

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

```
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Name | 1   | 4   | 3   | 2   |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| ...  | ... | ... | ... | ... |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

And I need my dataframe to be re-arranged like this:

```
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Name | 1   | 2   | 3   | 4   |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| ...  | ... | ... | ... | ... |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

with text first, then numbers in increasing order.

I have tried doing:

`df[sorted(df.columns)]`

But it doesn't work as the columns are of `string` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with convert columns to integers with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`, so missing values for non numbers are created. Then is used parameter `na_position='first'` for starts by this columns and then are values sorted by numerics:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','1','10','7', '6'])

df=df.sort_index(axis=1,key=lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce'),na_position='first')
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, 1, 6, 7, 10]
Index: []
```

If values are only numbers is used [`Index.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.astype.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['1','10','7', '6'])

df = df.sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.astype(int))
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1, 6, 7, 10]
Index: []
```

**Or:**

```
df = df[sorted(df.columns,key=lambda x:int(x))]
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1, 6, 7, 10]
Index: []
```